# MATLAB resets the values of variables

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I'm new to MATLAB and I created a program where I'm trying a similar situation to this

```
Pushbutton1

a = 1
b = 1
c = 1

if (level==1) then
newsize=<some calculations here>
a = newsize

elseif (level==2)
newsize=<some calculations here>
b = newsize

else
newsize=<some calculations here>
c = newsize

end

plot(a,b,c)
```

But when the 'level' changes, it has to update the 'newsize' on a/b/c . But each time i click the button, the previous variables are being reset. I understand that is logically correct for the program to reset the values, but I cant figure a way to basically "save" the values. I don't if I'm too tired to see this or its more complicated than this, so i would appreciate if you helped me on that!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the past values you can just do this:

```
a =  [a newsize];
```

That way when you go through you will add all of the values to an ever increasing list instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the [GUIDE tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guide.html) to [interactively build](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html) the interface, or did you do it [programmatically](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-build-matlab-guis.html)?

If you are using GUIDE, you could use the [`handles` structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guihandles.html) passed to each callback function along with the [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) function to store/retrieve the values.

If you building a GUI programmatically, you could use [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-73993) to create a closure over variables in the parent function's scope.

Of course there is also [global](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variables, [persistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables, and data stored in GUI components (inside the `UserData` property, or with [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html)/[`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) functions)

There is a section in the documentation about [sharing data between callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) if you want to read about the various methods.